# Vue Js - How to disable all inputs after loaded data

Tags: vue.js, input, disable

I have many inputs on my forms. After I got data from API, I looped to display all inputs. Then I want to disable them. ***I do not want to disable all inputs one by one on my loop***, because I had many loops and inputs on my forms. I want to write a block of code can solved my problem.

I try to use this code for disable them, but it can only disabled on input that created before load data.

```
let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `vue.js` then you can set a veriable like `disable` and set it like this

```html
<template>
<input type="text" :disabled="disable">
<input type="text" :disabled="disable">
<input type="text" :disabled="disable">
.
.
.
</template>
```

and in vue script

```js
data() {
   return {
   // other vars,
   disable: false,
   }
},
methods: {
   methodToLoadData() {
    // Load data
    this.disable = true;
   },
},
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I have a big note. Pls follow it. Thanks. Your answer is not correct for my question.

Comment: @MengsengOeng what note ?

Comment: I do not want to disable all inputs one by one on my loop, because ...

Comment: <template>
<div v-for="data in dataLoaded">
<input type="text" >
<input type="text" >
<input type="text" >
...
...
</div>

Comment: it means multiple input tags; not loop. I dont know how may input tag you have, you said multiple.

Comment: one `disable` variable; set it 'true' once after loading data; it disables all input tags where you set `:disabled="disable"`

Comment: I do not  follow your way, because it so many times for change my code. For example, if I have 10 inputs and 10 forms. I will add :disabled="disable" 100 times.

Comment: If I use loop it to easy and I changed only one time.

Comment: @MengsengOeng then execute the loop for disabling inputs after loading data; that also works; **BUT YOU DONT WANT LOOPS**

Comment: NO. On my question say "I try to use this code for disable them, but it can only disabled on input that created before load data.". Please read my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227476/discussion-between-ashwin-bande-and-mengseng-oeng).